# ROBLOX LUA: game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):PromptGamePassPurchase issue (no error message)

Tags: lua, roblox

This code is for a player to receive a pop-up to purchase a gamepass when a part is touched.

```
local sign = script.Parent.Parent

sign.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart)
     local player = otherPart.Parent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Player")
     if player then
          game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):PromptGamePassPurchase(player, 17103468)
     end
end)
```

I've tried putting a print command in the if statement, and it comes out into the console, but when I put the code for the gamepass pop-up, it doesn't work, and there is no error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between a [Player](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Player) and their [Character model](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Player/Character). The Player is the object in the Players service that represents the person in Roblox, and their Character is their physical presence in the Workspace.

When you say...

```
local player = otherPart.Parent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Player")
```

You are telling an object in the Workspace to find a Player instance. But Player instances are only in the Players service. So the `player` variable is always nil. That is why it never gets inside the if-statement.

You can fix this by using the [Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Players/GetPlayerFromCharacter) function. You pass in a character model, and the Players service will give the corresponding player (if it exists).

```
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local sign = script.Parent.Parent

sign.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart)
    local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(otherPart.Parent)
    if player then
        MarketplaceService:PromptGamePassPurchase(player, 17103468)
    end
end)
```